# Spring Security Oauth2 configuration with client authentication and user authentication

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on a project to setup oauth2 authorization. I already have brief knowledge on authentication process for spring security, but here when i setup oauth, i'm wondering how to do the authentication part? as here i both need to authenticate the clients credentials and also the user credentials( user authenticate will be do by LDAP), as the grant type would be 'password'. and after authentication, the final authenticated authentication object would be the user with his/her authorities, instead of the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you either use Resource Owner Credentials or whatever other grant type that could potentially take client(program) credential and user's credential when issuing a access token, then Authentication instance you are going to get from AuthenticationManager#authenticate() will be OAuth2Authentication. And inside of OAuth2Authentication, you'll able to see another Authentication which includes user's authentication information.

With that OAuth2Authentication, you can either manaully add logic to check different stuff you'd like to by accessing OAuth2Authentication itself by getting it from SecurityContextHolder.getContext()and then typecasting to OAuth2Authenticaiton, or simply use existing PreAuthorized annotation with SpringEL.